# printf formatting with php and integer values

Tags: php, printf

I was trying to use printf for formatting but I realized that when I use `%d`, I can't use `0` for the padding specifier with `-` alignment. Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
    $a = sprintf("%04d",5);
    $b = sprintf("%'1-4d",5); 
    $c = sprintf("%0-4d",5); 
    $d = sprintf("%0-4s",5); 

    var_dump($a);//outputs 0005

    var_dump($b);//outputs 5111

    var_dump($c);//outputs 5(and 4 spaces) why not 5000?

    var_dump($d);//outputs 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP is trying to think for you here.

If you right-pad `5` with four `0` characters, how would you be able to tell the difference between that and `50000`?  Or between `5` right padded with four `0` characters and `50` right padded with three `0` characters?

I don't have PHP handy to test, but what if you tried to use the format `"%'0-4d"` to convince it to do what you want?

Comment: I thougth this too but then why does it allow 5111? I also have tried %'0-4d, it also outputs 5.

Comment: I would guess it allows `5111` because it simply sees `1` as a padding character, but `0` has some semantic meaning.  I think it may be time to [file a bug report against php](https://bugs.php.net/).